# How to distinguish the XERO contacts?

Tags: xero-api

When I hit the XERO API
URL - https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/contacts
I will get the list of Contacts but I would like to separate these contacts such as Employees, Customers, Suppliers.
I have seen in the response these 2 XML tags are exists (/IsSupplier), (/IsCustomer) but I didn't find (/IsEmployee) tag.
Please share if any inputs?
Also https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/employees
is not returning any records also Employees are exists.

Answer (score 1):

"Employee" contacts are a deprecated concept for Xero organisations in the countries where we have a full payroll product (AU,NZ,UK).

To get employees from orgs in those countries you need to use the employees endpoint on the applicable payroll API e.g. https://developer.xero.com/documentation/payroll-api/employees